# Visual Studio got corrupted on Mac

Tags: macos, crash, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After Visual Studio crashed, it started to behave unexpectedly and keeps crashing even more. When run, it's showing some weird characters as shown below:

[image: Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac crashed & corrupted]

and it is also missing some extensions which can't be started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running, this command should check where Visual Studio stores its caches and other files:

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep VisualStudio)
```

Then removal of cache folder should solve the problem after quitting the app:

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.visual-studio
```